# SQL Server : success and failure combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Transactions` with these columns:

```
Invoice Number
Status (failed, success or defect)
```

I basically want a query which allows me to select all the invoice_numbers from the transactions table that have failed, then failed again (basically all invoices that have never managed to pass).

So most of the invoices in the table above can either be a success immediately, fail then be a success or fail and then fail. I want the fail and be a fail.

For example if I had this data in the table:

```
Invoice Number   |   Status
-----------------+----------    
111              |   Fail    
111              |   Success    
222              |   Fail    
222              |   Fail    
222              |   Fail
```

I want a query that returns all invoices like 222. It has failed and never been a success.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Did you mean to tag this `SQL-Server`? If not SQL Server which DB engine are you using?

Comment: Yes SQL-Server, have amended tag

Comment: If you just need to validate against all then use `NOT EXISTS`, if you want to check latestest records against previous ones then you need `LAG` window function to retrieve the previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following query should work for your case.

Using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
 SELECT 1 FROM Transactions T2
 WHERE T2.[Invoice Number] = T1.[Invoice Number] AND T2.Status='Success'
)
```

Using `NOT IN`

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions T1
WHERE [Invoice Number] NOT IN
(
 SELECT DISTINCT [Invoice Number] FROM Transactions WHERE  Status='Success'
)
```

**Note:** 
If you want distinct records, you can either use `GROUP BY` or simply use `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` clause

Answer (score 1):

You can also do the aggregation :

```
select t.InvoiceNumber
from table t 
group by InvoiceNumber
having min(status) = max(status) and min(status) = 'Fail';
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP wants `= 'Fail'` or `<> 'Pass'`, but the approach fits the problem better because the OP wants `invoicenumbers`, not transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select distinct invoice_number
from transactions
where invoice_number not in (select invoice_number 
                            from transactions 
                            where status = 'Pass')
```

Ie. get all the invoice numbers that are successful, and do not select them.